# Why would a TableAdapter populate a DataSet with "1/1/2000" for an entire timestamp column?

Tags: .net, datetime, postgresql, timestamp, tableadapter

I have a `TableAdapter` filling a `DataSet`, and for some reason every select query populates my timestamp column with the value **1/1/2000** for every selected row.

I first verified that original values are intact in the database side; most are, though a few rows lost their original value because of update queries performed programmatically before the issue was discovered.

The `DataColumn.DataType` is `DateType`, while the PgSQL database column type is `timestamp`. I recently noticed the issue in a bound `DataGridView` control, and confirmed this is not related to my data-binding by using the *Preview Data* option in the Visual Studio DataSet Editor.

After checking properties and types, and even recreating the `TableAdapter` from scratch, I'm pretty baffled. What I can do to fix the issue and/or diagnose the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The framework (eg. `DataTable` properties) doesn't know the source type of a table field; there's simply a **DataType** property that indicates what it expects to be able to convert the field value into.

The framework expects a date type for converting to `DateTime`, so timestamp values need to be converted in the query (ex. *SELECT timestamp::date FROM table*) or the conversion will fail, giving a value of **1/1/2000**.